# Rest api get curl C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, curl

I am getting 401 access error when running the below code. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. thanks

The Curl provided is:      curl -X GET --header "Authorization: " --header "Authorization: Bearer kgffj*dfkgj40fdgjkjkdfjUHHHDNhdfj" "https://api.united.com/v1/accounts"

```
 string url = "https://api.united.com/v1/accounts";
        WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
        string credentials = "kgffj*dfkgj40fdgjkjkdfjUHHHDNhdfj";
        CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
        myReq.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
        WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(content);
        var json = "[" + content + "]"; // change this to array
        var objects = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array  
        foreach (JObject o in objects.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
            {
                string name = p.Name;
                string value = p.Value.ToString();
                Console.Write(name + ": " + value);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curl request would be represented like this in C#

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://api.united.com/v1/accounts"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer kgffj*dfkgj40fdgjkjkdfjUHHHDNhdfj"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

I could not test this code as the url https://api.united.com/v1/accounts times out from my system. But This should work.

As others have pointed out you should not need to convert the token to base 64 as its not converted to base64 in the curl

I am assuming that you want to perform the same request that you would run if you use the curl command in your question

The code provided above fixes the http request.
The response object in the above code is of Type [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netcore-3.1)
This object has a [HttpResponseMessage.Content Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Http_HttpResponseMessage_Content) on it
This Content is of type [HttpContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=netcore-3.1) and it has a public method [ReadAsStringAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Http_HttpContent_ReadAsStringAsync) which will

> Serialize the HTTP content to a string as an asynchronous operation.

and that is your JSON content that you are looking for.

So your code should look like this

```
public static async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {

    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://api.united.com/v1/accounts"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer kgffj*dfkgj40fdgjkjkdfjUHHHDNhdfj"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
}
```

This method is an async method,Since the code you provided in the question is not async you would need to use

```
string json = GetData().Result;
```

if you want to use it in a non async function
or if you change your method calling this method to async then you can use the await keyword like this

```
string json = await GetData();
```

Comment: You can use a tool like https://curl.olsh.me/ to get your curl command in other languages like c# or python etc

Comment: I am using the code above. The connection is ok, but I am not getting Json Data. StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.Stream
Content, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-API-Version: 1.11.5
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Comment: see my fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/J7WnZ1
await httpClient.SendAsync(request) returns HttpResponseMessage object
which has a Content property which is an HttpContent and that has a public method ReadAsStringAsync which will give you your Json Data.
Refer to the fiddle to see how I used it to get my string.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide the json content from the response variable. Do upvote if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you can just hardcode an OAuth Bearer token. You need to lookup the details for authentication for that specific API to see how to obtain a Bearer token for use in the API.